# Pigeonhole Principle Example

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> Within any group of 13 people, there must be two who have their birthdays in the same month.

Wouldn't we be able to draw this conclusion only if it is assumed each person has a unique birthday month?

Comment: How could a single person have more than one birth month?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig isn't there the possibility that out of the 13 people, multiple could have the same birthday month though?

Comment: @lulu, there could be multiple people with the same birth month

Comment: @AmanuelEphrem yeah, but you have to be careful with wordphrasing. In this context, "two" and "exactly two" are different

Comment: @FormerMath, could you expand on that? Sorry, I'm not quite grasping what you are trying to say.

Comment: Of course there could be several people with the same birth month.  In fact, there have to be (if you have $13$ or more people).  That's exactly what you are asked to prove.

Comment: If it’s true for three it’s still true for two.

Comment: @AmanuelEphrem The problems states that "there must be two (...)". This statement allows two, three or even more people to have birthday in the same month. A different story would be if the problem was "there must be *exactly* two (...)"

Comment: Oh shit I just got it!! Thanks everyone, especially @lulu and@FormerMath.

Comment: Suppose they were all born in February. Then pick two of them. Those two have their birthdays in the same month.

Comment: Actually, I think that the OP has a legitimate complaint here, assuming that the problem is being quoted verbatim (i.e. correctly).  As stated, the problem is ambiguous, and could intend either *exactly two people* or *at least two people*.  Certainly, one might surmise that the latter meaning is intended, because that intent facilitates using the pigeonhole principle.  However, the OP shouldn't have to *reverse-engineer* the problem's intent.  Ambiguity, for the sake of brevity, is a common flaw in math problem statements.